# *ngFor Directive not Showing Menu Item Data for Context Menu Right Click in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, contextmenu

I am having issues with using a right click function in my context menu. My menu item are not showing up because of my second ngFor="let row" condition... but I need the selected row object from a right click in order to pass in a json value from the row.

Right now the modal is popping up, but no menu item buttons are showing so I am unable to use the click event.

What am I doing wrong here?

**view.component.html**

```
  <!--Context Right Click Menu-->
  <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let funct of FunctionNames">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let row">
        <div mat-menu-item>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(row)">{{funct}}</button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

  </mat-menu>

  <!--Context Right Click Menu-->
  <mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let funct of FunctionNames">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let row">
        <div mat-menu-item>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(row)">{{funct}}</button>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

  </mat-menu>
```

**view.component.ts**

```
onContextMenuAction(row: any) {
        console.log(row);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a reference to an angular material menu data in the template.

You can do it using: `let-refrenceName="dataItemKey"`.

it will get a refrence called `refrenceName`, to the menu data with key name: `dataItemKey`.

In your case it's like: `let-row="row"`

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-row="row">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(row)">Action 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(row)">Action 2</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Also make sure to set the `row` menu data like :

```
this.contextMenu.menuData = { 'row': yourValue };
```

so you can reference it.

[Full live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu-dfxhgj?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

The second `*ngFor` doesn't contain an array to loop on. If you need index you can directly get index in your first

```
<mat-menu #contextMenu="matMenu" #contextMenu2="matMenu">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let funct of FunctionNames">
        <div mat-menu-item>
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction(funct)">{{funct}}</button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-menu>
```

Component

```
onContextMenuAction(funct) {
  // you should get entire row data here 
}
```

Comment: I just updated my code... so I need the selected row object value... not necessary the index

Comment: If your inspiration to use let row is material data table then I don't think that same principle can be applied here, for the complete row you can simply return `funct` as a parameter and then manipulate data as per your need in the component

Comment: How does that look in code? I’m kind of confused at the answer